# Only 6 Months in Life span US Tourist Visa

Tags: visas, usa, tourist-visas

If a person is an Indian by birth, but he is currently living in London, and has good financial circumstances,  
can he visit the US every year for 2 months to explore the landscapes and geographies of the USA? Or that is not Possible and one is allowed only for 6 months (6 months may extend over many years, but the total should be 6 months only) in total in his entire life span to visit the USA.

Comment: If everything is *as you say*, there is simply NO lifetime limit, only each-trip limits.  That's it.  Of course, *in any circumstance whatsoever, with no limits whatsoever*, the official at the US border may refuse you if they think you are trying to game (some) system.  But I doubt you'd have any problem whatsoever. Visiting the US "every year" is totally commonplace.  I bet there are literally millions who visit *every single year* of their life for a shopping trip, long Sun holiday in Florida, or whatever tourist reason.  You have no issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual limit is six months per visit.  This is codified at [8 CFR 214.2(b)(2)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/214.2#b_2):

> **Minimum six month admissions.** Any B-2 visitor who is found otherwise admissible and is issued a Form I-94 (see § 1.4), will be admitted for a minimum period of six months, regardless of whether less time is requested, provided, that any required passport is valid as specified in section 212(a)(26) of the Act. Exceptions to the minimum six month admission may be made only in individual cases upon the specific approval of the district director for good cause.

Comment: So say in 10 years a person can visit 2-3 months/year and that is possible.

Comment: @wocommerce115 Yes, there's no lifetime limit of any kind for visits to the US. You may get questions about what you're doing in the US and your circumstances at home, but there's no inherent problem with annual visits or visiting more than six months in your lifetime. However, in a comment on a now deleted answer, you said that the purpose of your visits would be to pursue a degree from Harvard extension school. A B-1/B-2 visa is for visitors, not students studying toward a degree, as the page I'll link below explains.

Comment: You'd need [the appropriate visa](https://www.extension.harvard.edu/registration-admissions/international-student-study-options) to come to the US to study there, and Harvard Extension does not sponsor student visas. Their site explains that there may be an option to get a visa through Harvard Summer School, but you'd want to talk to them and be absolutely sure it's possible to complete your program in this way, or you could waste a lot of time and money. Alternatively, you could consider another school.

Comment: Just to emphasize: "Attempting to enter the United States in ESTA or the B-2 visa status to earn credit is a violation of US visa policy and you risk being denied entry to the United States. This is true for non-degree students as well as admitted degree candidates. Only noncredit study is permissible." This is all very different than a series of trips to "explore the landscapes and geographies of the USA."